# Как работает итератор в дереве?

Tags: c++, бинарное-дерево, итераторы

Хочу написать итератор для самописного дерева (авл), но не могу понять как должен вести себя итератор во время инкременирования? Тоесть, в зависимости от положения элеманта, на который указывает итератор (нахождение в правой или левой ветке) он должен поступать по разному. К тому же он должен иметь возможность подниматься вверх по дереву, но узлы указывают только на потомков, а не на родителей. Нужно дописывать в каждый узел указатель на потомка? Как подобная задача решена в `stl`?

Comment: Итератор  не должен поступать никак.  Итератор должен иметь некоторые функциональности, необходимые для реализации дерева. А именно, вы должны определить он должен иметь категорию случайного доступа,  или должен быть однонаправленный?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan мне нужен однонаправленный итератор, но как ему обходить дерево, если у узлов нет указателя на родителя?

Comment: Имхо, иметь указатель на родителя - лучше всего. Можно конечно хранить в итераторе весь путь от корня до вершины, на которую он указывает, но мне эта идея не нравится.

Comment: Либо, хранить указатели на  весь стек узлов дерева в итераторе. Либо Хранить в итераторе ID узла + указатель на дерево (и производить поиск в дереве каждый раз при разименовывании). Либо хранить указатели на родителя в узлах дерева, ... Несть числа вариантам. Все зависит от ограничений, которые вы накладываете на свой итреатор и дерево.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat указатели на потомков есть (два: налево и направо), нету указателя на предка

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  скорее вам нужен двунаправленный итератор, и вы в классе дерева должны хранить итератор  begin  указывающий на корень дерева, тогда от него и плясать...

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Да, точно. Опечатался. :/

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вопрос в инкреминировании итератора: даже если в дереве и указать итератор на начало (который, кстати, будет совсем не в корне дерева!) то как это отразится на операторе  `++`  для итератора? Ведь класс итератора не сможет им воспользоваться.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, на всякий случай:       typeid (iterator_traits< map<int, int>::iterator>::iterator_category)  == typeid(bidirectional_iterator_tag

Comment: libstdc++ использует указатель на родителя: [stl_tree.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/libstdc%2B%2B-html-USERS-4.1/stl__tree_8h-source.html):98. (Там деревья красно-черные, но по идее это неважно.)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan нет, стоп! Почему это:  "что будет указывать итератор после инкрементирования ... это вы должны реализовать в классе дерева"? Нет!! Конкретно инкременирование должно быть, как раз таки, в классе итератор, а не в классе дерева.

Comment: Обход дерева итератором (как, впрочем и обход любого ациклического графа) - это классическое правило обхода лабиринта по "правилу правой руки" (или левой): всегда следуем правой стены, т.е. на каждой развилке лабиринта поворачиваем направо. Если в дереве есть указатели на предков, то такой обход реализуется тривиально. Если указателей на предков нет, то придется недостающие "мостики" хранить в итераторе (путь от корня дерева до текущей вершины). А дальше только остается вопрос о том, какой порядок обхода вам нужен, т.е. в какой момент итератор должен приостанавливаться в процессе обхода.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan смотрите: у вас в контейнере Stack (объект stack) есть итератор и вы создаете переменную с этим типом - `auto alfa = stack.begin();` а дальше его инкреминируете: `++alfa` - и как итератор должен инкреминироваться, если у вас операция инкремента определена в классе Stack?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, вы меня не понели, я хочу сказать какраз,  пока вы не напишете класс, не сможете и написать для него итератор. Для каждого класса  итератор ведет себя по разному.  В вашем примере  stack уже написан, поэтому в нем можно использовать итератор подходящей категории и  уже от  реализации этого класса  будет зависить на что будет указывать итератор после каждой операции. Ладно, раз уж вы меня не понели, значит я плохо формулирую свой ответ... Итераторный тип всегда зависит от реализации класса....

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch,  в двух своих комментах я просто неправильно выразился( моя вина)...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat разве есть дял итератора разница сбалансированное или нет дерево???

Comment: @Andrey Нет. А разве я что-то другое писал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если вы хотите реализовать "лековесный" итератор по дереву, то да, в такой ситуации вам придется тем или иным образом в узлах дерева также хранить указатели на их предка. Детали такого хранения могут отличаться, но общая идея остается неизменной: надо уметь по данному узлу дерева определить его предка на основе информации, хранящейся именно в самом дереве.

   Если такое хранение реализовано в самом дереве, то обход дерева итератором становиться относительно тривиальной задачей (в зависимости от того, какой порядок обхода вам нужен).
2. Если вы не имеете возможности хранения связи потомок-предок в самом дереве, то "лековесного" итератора не получится: каждый итератор должен будет хранить внутри себя "тяжеловесное" состояние. А именно: путь от корня дерева до текущего узла дерева. Этот путь и даст итератору возможность возвращаться из потомка в передка, когда такая необходимость возникает в процессе обхода.

Разумеется, если у вас есть выбор, наиболее разумным является именно первый вариант с "лековесным" итератором. Именно так это и реализуется в STL.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как написаны итераторы для стандартных контейнеров, но чтобы выразить свое мнение,  написал незаконченный и недоработанный класс дерева со своим итератором:

```
template <class T>
class Tree {
    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node *parent;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
        Node(const T& t) :
            data(t), left(0), right(0), parent(0) {}
    };
    Node  *current;
    std::less<int> cmp;
public:
    Tree(const T& t = T()) : current(new Node(t)) {}
    ~Tree();
    Tree(const Tree &);
    Tree& operator =(const Tree&);
    using Itcat = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
    void insert(const T&);
   // ищем в ветке, с конкретным корнем, предыдущий  элемент по компаратору
    Node* next_element(Node*);
    // указатель  на следующий элемент  по компаратору
    Node* prev_element(Node*);

    struct iterator : public std::iterator<Itcat,Tree<T>::Node>
    {
        using It = std::iterator<Itcat,Tree<T>::Node>;
        using reference = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;
        Node* cur;
        iterator(Node* p = nullptr) : cur(p) {}
        reference operator *() { return *cur;  }
        // если, допустим вы хотите, чтобы после ++ итератор указывал на
        // следующий элемент по возрастанию, что вполне естественно
        // для копаратора less<T>
        iterator& operator ++() {
            // current должен указывать на предыдущий элемент по компаратору
            //для нашего  копаратора
            if(cur->right)
              cur = next_element(cur->right);
            else {
              cur = next_element(cur->parent);
            }
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& operator --() {
            if(cur->left)
                cur = prev_element(cur->left);
            return *this;
        }
    };
};
```

Демонстрация того, что пока вы не напишете свой класс, не выразите пожелания, какой элемент вы хотите получать с помощью итератора и при дальнейших операций с ним, то невозможно написать для него итератор, ведущий себя корректно. Т.е. итераторный класс в своей реализации зависит от класса, чьим итератором он является. Ведь деревья бывают разные и написаны разным стилем...  Вы в вопросе не показали нужную информацию о вашем классе, и мне кажется, поэтому вы до сих пор не получили конкретного ответа

Comment: ну вообще ответ на мой вопрос я уже получил: в комментариях, где предложили использовать стэк - этого мне вполне достаточно. К тому же я указывал, что элементы дерева не указывают на родителя - в этом и была вся проблематика! Если у ноды родитель есть, то никакого вопроса нет, так, как итератор может беспрепятственно обойти все дерево. Но не в случае, когда у ноды нет родителя - тогда итератор никак не сможет обратится к родителю - в этом и был вопрос! Тобишь есть (о тех что я знаю) два решения: дописать родителя или сделать стэк внутри итератора (что я сейчас и делаю).