# Как реализовать методы begin() и end() в итераторе для binary-search tree?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, дерево, итераторы

Как реализовать методы begin() и end() в итераторе для binary-search tree? Не понимаю, на что указывает эти итераторы для BST. Хочу реализовать обход BST как абстрактного контейнера в STL, примерно так

```
for(tree::iterator it = tree.begin(); it!= tree.end(); it++){
    //какие-то действия
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как работает итератор в дереве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853723/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: В дополнение к вышеприведенному хочу поделиться соображениями по поводу `end`. Получение этого итератора может быть довольно нетривиальной учитывая структуру дерева. Как очевидное решение - хранить указатель на последню ноду в дереве, но это плохое решение, так как потребует дополнительной логики и проверок. Вместо этого лучше рассматривать ваше дерево как левое поддерево более крупного. Таким образом ваш итератор `end` будет как бы указывать на родителя корня вашего дерева - это позволит не внедрять вообще никакой дополнительной логики

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в структуре дерева должны быть явные связи с родительским узлом?

Comment: не обязательно, можно обойтись без связей к родителю. Для этого в итераторе должен быть стэк посещённых узлов. Также добавление или удаление ноды инвалидирует такой итератор

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к вышеприведенному хочу поделиться соображениями по поводу end. Получение этого итератора может быть довольно нетривиальной учитывая структуру дерева. Как очевидное решение - хранить указатель на последню ноду в дереве, но это плохое решение, так как потребует дополнительной логики и проверок. Вместо этого лучше рассматривать ваше дерево как левое поддерево более крупного. Таким образом ваш итератор end будет как бы указывать на родителя корня вашего дерева - это позволит не внедрять вообще никакой дополнительной логики

не обязательно, можно обойтись без связей к родителю. Для этого в итераторе должен быть стэк посещённых узлов. Также добавление или удаление ноды инвалидирует такой итератор

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853723/Как-работает-итератор-в-дереве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853723/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5)